# Properly versioning a private composer repository

Tags: git, package, repository, composer-php, private

I have a private repository in Git and I have managed to make it work with composer properly as a package. However, there is one thing that I dislike : When I specify the version of the repository, I have to say `dev-master`, to get the master branch. What I would like instead is to be able to specify a repository version. So, how do I configure my repository to allow the other repositories that use it as a dependency with a version identifier ?

This is my package's composer.json, which resides in my one and only `master` branch :

```
{
    "name": "username/packagename",
    "type": "mytype",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

And then in another project where I want to include this package I have this composer.json:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@githost:username/packagename.git/"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "username/packagename": "dev-master"
  },
}
```

As you can see, I have to say `'dev-master'` to get my package from my master branch, but I want to be able to say '1.0.0' or '^1.0.0' or any other composer versioning operation available. What do I have to do in my package structure to enable proper versioning behaviour ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tag, and before that: **remove that `version` entry** in the `composer.json` file.

Usage example for creating a tag on the master branch:

```
git checkout master
git tag -a 1.0.0
git push --follow-tags
```

Using annotated tags will record the date and username creating the tag. Git will ask for a message, which is rather irrelevant for most people, so you can fill in anything you like. I usually opt for repeating the tag name.

Removing the `version` entry before tagging a version should be obvious. :)

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for your help, could you give me a basic example of usage ?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot Sven, I got it working ! Now I specified a version "^1.0.0" and it's working fine, I hope it will still work after I add a new version :) Just a note: Probably you meant `git tag -a v1.0.0` instead ? Because I added a version tag without v in the front and it was not udentified by composer.

Comment: Using `v` in front is optional, it should have worked without it. I suspect a temporary problem somewhere, but as long as it works in the end, I wouldn't mind too much at this point.

Comment: You're right Sven, on my new package commit, I added a tag without a 'v' prefix and from my other project composer updated the dependency to new version properly. Probably something slipped the last time, thanks again, cheers !